# Questions about Cassy

Tags: scalardb, cassy

I would like to ask a few questions about a tool called Cassy that supports ScalarDB.

https://github.com/scalar-labs/cassy

1. Can I trust the "status" of rpc.Cassy.ListBackups to confirm the success of a backup?
   Or do I need to check the file manually?
2. Is it safe to assume that the output of rpc.Cassy.ListBackups is in desc order of "created_at"?
3. What does Cassy do when I manually delete a backup file?
   For example, does rpc.Cassy.ListBackups continue to show the deleted files?
   What happens when I specify a deleted snapshot in rpc.Cassy.RestoreBackup?
4. About restore
   restore_type=2, no target_ips
   and
   restore_type=1
   What is the distinction between

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Can I trust the "status" of rpc.Cassy.ListBackups to confirm the success of a backup? Or do I need to check the file manually?

Yes, you can trust the "status" of rpc.Cassy.ListBackups.

> 2. Is it safe to assume that the output of rpc.Cassy.ListBackups is in desc order of "created_at"?

Yes, output of rpc.Cassy.ListBackups is in desc order of "created_at"

> 3. What does Cassy do when I manually delete a backup file? For example, does rpc.Cassy.ListBackups continue to show the deleted files? What happens when I specify a deleted snapshot in rpc.Cassy.RestoreBackup?

> > What does Cassy do when I manually delete a backup file?

Cassy status will not be updated when you manually delete a backup from cloud storage.

> > For example, does rpc.Cassy.ListBackups continue to show the deleted files?

Cassy will show the backup creation status, which means if the backup creation fails it will show the status as failed, and if successful it will show the status as success. Manual deletion of backup files does not affect the status of Cassy rpc.Cassy.ListBackups.

> > What happens when I specify a deleted snapshot in rpc.Cassy.RestoreBackup?

rpc.Cassy.RestoreBackup will fail.

> 4. About restore restore_type=2, no target_ips and restore_type=1 What is the distinction between

restore_type=2 and restore_type=1 will restore backup files to all Cassandra nodes.

**restore_type=1**

restore_type=1 will restore cluster-backup (snapshots) backup file to all Cassandra nodes.

**restore_type=2**

restore_type=2 will restore node-backup (snapshots and incremental) backup files to all Cassandra nodes.

restore_type=2 with snapshot-only=true will restore node-backup (snapshots) backup files to all Cassandra nodes